# MySQL/MariaDB GROUP BY, ORDER BY returns same result twice

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, mariadb

Assume I have the following table

```
+----+--------+--------+
| id | result | person |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 |      1 |      1 |
|  2 |      2 |      2 |
|  3 |      2 |      2 |
|  4 |      4 |      3 |
|  5 |      4 |      1 |
|  6 |      1 |      2 |
+----+--------+--------+
```

Now I want to get the best result by each person ordered high to low, where best result means highest value of the `result`-column, so basically I want to GROUP BY `person` and ORDER BY `result`. Also if a person has the same result more than one time, I only want to return want one of those results. So the return I want is this:

```
+----+--------+--------+
| id | result | person |
+----+--------+--------+
|  4 |      4 |      3 |
|  5 |      4 |      1 |
|  2 |      2 |      2 |
+----+--------+--------+
```

The following query almost gets me there:

```
SELECT id, groupbytest.result, groupbytest.person
FROM groupbytest
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(result) as res, person
    FROM groupbytest
    GROUP BY person
) AS tmp
ON groupbytest.result = tmp.res
AND groupbytest.person = tmp.person
ORDER BY groupbytest.result DESC;
```

but returns two rows for the same person, if this person has made the same best result twice, so what I get back is

```
+----+--------+--------+
| id | result | person |
+----+--------+--------+
|  4 |      4 |      3 |
|  5 |      4 |      1 |
|  2 |      2 |      2 |
|  3 |      2 |      2 |
+----+--------+--------+
```

If two results for the same person are similar, only the one with lowest id should be returned, so instead of returning rows with ids 2 and 3, only row with id 2 should be returned.

Any ideas how to implement this?

Comment: In the event of a tie, what should happen instead?

Comment: @Strawberry only one (let's say the one with the lowest id) of the results should be returned. So instead of returning rows with id 2 and 3, only row with id 2 should be returned.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ttable.* from ttable 
inner join 
(
SELECT max(ttable.id) as maxid  FROM `ttable` 
inner join  (SELECT max(`result`) as res, `person` FROM `ttable` group by person) t
on
ttable.result = t.res
and
ttable.person =  t.person

group by ttable.person ) tt
on
ttable.id = tt.maxid
```

Comment: Hi @OTARIKI. Thanks for the suggestion, but this only works, when min(result) == max(result). I reality person 2 could also have a worse result (e.g. 1), in which case it would still return 2 rows with result 2.
I've updated the question to include another row in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Check if tmp results in the correct resulting table. I think tmp should group correctly. The join adds new rows, because you have different values of "id".
Hence the rows with different id's will be treatet as different rows, no matter if the other columns are equal. You do not have duplicate results as long as there is no duplicate id. Try to remove the id from the SELECT. Then you should have the result you wanted, but without the id.

Example: Imagine Rooms with your id's from above. Let result be the amount of tables in the room and person the amount of people. Just because you have randomly the same amount of tables and people in room 2 and 3, it doesn't mean, that this are the same rooms.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the fast reply. `tmp` does contain the correct results, but not (nescessarily) in the right order. Also I want to get the id of the result as well as the result and the person, so removing not SELECTing id is not really what I am after.